# Is the color highlighting of "interesting" questions wrong?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, tag-watching, design

I've noticed that the highlight color of "interesting" questions often causes me to subconsciously skip over them - opposite of the intended effect. It makes them look similar to ads that are stuck in the middle of search results.

Maybe I'm the only one who does this, but it might be worth noting.

Comment: In which S[OFU] site? The color varies among those 3+1 sites

Comment: Randell: SO

Comment: I think highlighting the tags themselves, rather than the entire question, would be more appropriate.

Comment: I find that, too.  I've been conditioned to ignore results with a different background color.  When the color appears and then fades away, that seems to capture my attention better.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those questions where each individual can really only answer for themselves.

Assuming you mean Stack Overflow, I don't find it has that effect at all - my only difficulty is that in some situations the difference in colour isn't obvious if you're viewing a screen from a non-ideal angle. (IIRC this particularly affects me on my phone, which makes it a less serious problem to start with.)

It might not be a bad idea to have a visual indicator *apart* from the background colour - although there's already a lot of information in the list, and adding much more clutter might not be a good idea.

How about changing the appearance of whichever tags contribute to the question being interesting? For instance, they could be made bold, or underlined. That might just give an extra hint without being too messy.

Answer (score 2):

To me it would make sense to be able to pick a color for the interested tags as part of your profile. It would be cooler to associate different tags with different colors, but I bet that's asking too much.

Comment: +1, the ability to pick the color of your interested tags would help avoid the awful peach color on SO.

Answer (score 0):

At least on SO, I can't say that. Quite the opposite: The highlighted questions jump right at your face, in my opinion. Don't know about the other sites.